# CSS - Align div in bottom of screen without using position: absolute

Tags: css, css-position, phonejs

I'm designing a PhoneJS app, and I need to have a button placed in the bottom of the screen, but without using `position: absolute`.

**Why don't I just use absolute?**

As this is a PhoneJS application, this causes problems when flipping the phone to landscape (refer below)

This is portrait (button placed correctly)

[image]

This is landscape (button misplaced)

[image]

How can one accomplish such task without using the `position: absolute` css attribute?

Comment: The problem is not the position. You need to make a media query to solve the landscape problem. Your only way to solve this is with position absolute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will still have the issue of two buttons and no space regardless of `position: absolute`.

I would suggest using a media query to target landscape and change the styles.

```
/* iPhone Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

  /* Styles go here */

}
```

[Media queries on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: As this is a PhoneJS, it's cross platform. Would this apply to Android and Windows Phone aswell? Isn't there a way of saying something like `if width > height` in css?

Comment: I have not tested on windows phone as they have such a minor market share but I would think the `orientation: landscape` query would be triggered there too. For Android phones will need to adjust the `pixel-ratio`,  `width` and `height` queries. See the article I linked to for a more in depth look.

Comment: It's supported in android aswell. Thank you for the answer. It works perfectly. I ended up designing them so that the the two buttons aren't underneath each other, but instead they're next to each other. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the @media tags for css in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table method like this in example. **http://jsfiddle.net/2232cyrq/**

make `height:100%` for `body and html` and main wrapper will stand as display: table and table-cell for bottom content